# Is there some way to remove UWP Button Click handler without event token?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

In an UWP app, there is a Button which has a Click handler(`1`) attached to it. I want to remove this handler and add my own one. It seems there are 2 ways:

1, I added a fake handler(`2`) , from the event token returned, I tried to guess the event token corresponding to the handler(`1`) and finally found it hard  to guess.

2, or is there some API that can remove the Click handler blindly ?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need the event token to remove the handler.

Comment: Nothing keeps you from storing the event token in case you later want to unregister your delegate. The fact that you don't have access to the event token suggests that you don't own the code whose behavior you want to modify. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Yes it's some kind of hacking. In fact , I'm trying to modify the behavior of the TextBox's clear button(```X```) with least effort. Now that none of the proposed methods works, I will seek other ways.

Comment: Change the X:Name of the TextBoxes clear button in its template and it will remove the default behaviour. Then you are free to do what you want with it. You may have to also update VisualStates in the template to reflect this name change.